# Kotlin equivalent of Swift's defer keyword

Tags: android, swift, kotlin, keyword

Is there anything similar in Kotlin that provides same ability as the Swift keyword 'defer' ?

What the defer key word does is, it ensure that the code inside a defer block get executed before returning from a function.

Below is an example imagining that defer keyword existed in Kotlin.

```
    class MyClass {

        var timeStamp = 0L

        fun isEdible(fruit: Fruit): Boolean {
          defer { 
           timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
          }
          if (fruit.isExpired) {
             return false
          }
          if (fruit.isRipe) {
            return true
          }
          return false
        }
     }
```

In the case above, regardless of at what point the function returns, the block inside `defer` will get executed and timestamp's value will get updated, just before the function ends.

I know Java there is the `finally {}` keyword used along with `try{} catch{}`, but it's is not exactly what defer offers.

Comment: I don't use swift, but is defer functionally an async thread that "joins" with main thread before method returns?

Comment: @Pawel `defer` in Swift simply executes the `defer` block after leaving the current scope (e.g. exiting a function).

Comment: `try`/`finally`, I think

Comment: I second @Alexander: a quick look at the grammar of Kotlin does point to the `finally` block. I recall reading an article a long time ago regarding Swift’s `defer`, describing it as ”`try` and `finally` done right”. So I believe the answer you’re likely to get is not the one you are looking for (Kotlin natively, at least).

Answer (score 8):

There's no such keyword in Kotlin, but you can make a construct yourself that will work quite similarly. Something like this (note that this does not handle exceptions in the deferred blocks):

```
class Deferrable {
    private val actions: MutableList<() -> Unit> = mutableListOf()

    fun defer(f: () -> Unit) {
        actions.add(f)
    }

    fun execute() {
        actions.forEach { it() }
    }
}

fun <T> defer(f: (Deferrable) -> T): T {
    val deferrable = Deferrable()
    try {
        return f(deferrable)
    } finally {
        deferrable.execute()
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
class MyClass {

    var timeStamp = 0L

    fun isEdible(fruit: Fruit): Boolean = defer { d ->
      d.defer { 
       timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
      }
      if (fruit.isExpired) {
         return false
      }
      if (fruit.isRipe) {
        return true
      }
      return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach! Try/Finally is definitely the more appropriate choice, but this is neat.

Comment: You could also change the top-level function to `fun <T> deferBlock(f: Deferrable.() -> T)` and use just `defer` inside instead of `d/it.defer`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I thought about that, but I decided I didn't want to change the value of `this` from `MyClass` to `Deferrable`.

Comment: Fair enough, just mentioning as an option.

Comment: @Alexander I changed the implementation to use try/finally. This will make the deferred blocks execute even though the function body throws an exception. I don't really know how Swift handles exceptions within the deferred blocks though. I didn't find anything with my quick Google search. Do you know?

Comment: @marstran I defer block always executes prior to a function's exit, no matter if an error is thrown or not.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, but if an exception is thrown within one of the defer blocks, what happens? Like if you would do `d.defer { throw RuntimeException() }`. Is the exception propagated out of the function, or will it just be swallowed? Will the other defer blocks still run? What happens if more than one defer block throws an exception?

Comment: @marstran idk, try it

Comment: You might want to change `actions` from a `MutableList ` to a `Stack`

Comment: @marstran You cannot use any return statements (e.g. `break`, `return`, `throw` etc.) in a `defer` block in Swift.

Answer (score 4):

The closest equivalent is `try`/`finally`. The `catch` clause is not necessary if you're not interested in catching any of the possible exceptions.

```
try {
    println("do something")
    // ... the rest of your method body here
}
finally {
    println("Don't forget about me!");
}
```

In Swift, `defer` is usually used to ensure you don't forget to clean up some kind of resource or another (file handle, database connection, shared memory map, etc.). For this purpose, Kotlin use `with`, which takes a closure, to which the resource is passed as an argument. The resource is valid for the lifetime of the closure, and is automatically closed at the end.

```
FileWriter("test.txt")
  .use { it.write("something") }
// File is closed by now
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same question today.

While I think the answer provided by marstran is good, I decided to refactor it a little bit.

```
fun <T> deferred(f: ((() -> Unit) -> Unit) -> T): T {
    val actions: MutableList<() -> Unit> = mutableListOf()
    try {
        return f(actions::add)
    } finally {
        actions.asReversed().forEach { it() }
    }
}
```

I got rid of the `Deferrable`  class by using the list directly in the `deffered` function. This also solves the fact that the whole `Deferrable` object was passed to the calling code needing to call `it.defer`/`d.defer`. In this version the `add` method of the mutable list is directly passed into the lambda allowing to have a code that is closer to its go/swift version.

To address the suggestion given by mvndaai to use `Stack` I decided to call `.asReversed()` on the list. Maybe there is a LI-FO type in kotlin that is also available in non JVM variants, but if not I think this is a good solution.

the given sample would look like:

```
class MyClass {

    var timeStamp = 0L

    fun isEdible(fruit: Fruit): Boolean = deferred { defer ->
      defer { 
       timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
      }
      if (fruit.isExpired) {
         return false
      }
      if (fruit.isRipe) {
        return true
      }
      return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with exception handling:

```kotlin
class DeferContext {
    private val list = mutableListOf<() -> Unit>()

    fun defer(payload: () -> Unit) {
        list += payload
    }

    /** lombok `@Cleanup` analog */
    fun AutoCloseable.deferClose() = apply {
        defer { close() }
    }

    fun executeDeferred(blockError: Throwable?) {
        var error: Throwable? = blockError
        for (element in list.reversed()) {
            try {
                element()
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                if (error == null) {
                    error = e
                } else {
                    error.addSuppressed(e)
                }
            }
        }
        error?.let { throw it }
    }
}

inline fun <T> deferBlock(payload: DeferContext.() -> T): T {
    val context = DeferContext()
    var error: Throwable? = null
    var result: T? = null
    try {
        result = context.payload()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        error = e
    } finally {
        context.executeDeferred(error)
    }
    return result as T
}
```

IMHO, main point of `defer` functionality is execution of deferred actions regardless of previously thrown exceptions.

usage:

```kotlin
deferBlock {
    defer { println("block exited") }
    val stream = FileInputStream("/tmp/a").deferClose()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class is `Closeable` you can use `use block`:

```kotlin
class MyClass : Closeable {
        var timeStamp = 0L

        override fun close() {
            timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }

        fun test(): Boolean {
            this.use {
                if (fruit.isExpired) {
                    return false
                }
                if (fruit.isRipe) {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        }
    }
```